# How to create socket over https in NestJs?

Tags: ssl, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I have created one socket gateway which is working very smoothly with an HTTP request. Now, I am trying to connect socket through https request in NestJs but didn't work for me.
I have also tried to give extra parameters in `@WebsocketGateway(5058, { origin : "*:*", secure: true })`

I have also checked for NestJs official documentation to work with SSL on the socket but found nothing.

Below is my code which I have created as per documentation.

```
import { InternalServerErrorException, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SocketService } from './socket/socket.service';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(5058, { origin : "*:*"} )
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayInit {

    constructor(private socketService: SocketService) { }

    public userIds = [];

    afterInit(server: Server) {
        console.log("Socket server started");
        this.socketService.socket = server;
    }

    async handleConnection(client) {

        try {
            console.log(client.id);
            this.socketService.socket.to(client.id).emit('status', "connected = " + client.id);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException(
                `Oops.something went wrong, please try again later`,
            );
        }
    }

    async handleDisconnect(client) {
        this.userIds = this.userIds.filter(user => user.conn_socket_id !== client.id);
    }
}
```

edited:

I can start server and access socket while using an HTTP request, but I am not able to access the socket on HTTPS request.
ex. http://example.com:5058 is working for me,
https://example.com:5058 is not working.

Comment: Please share your code instead of a sreenshot if you want other developers to help you properly

Comment: What problem do you face? The server doesn't start? You cant connect to the server once it is launched?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using a proxy over the socket port so if my socket URL is like **https://example.com:5058** then it should be handled from the virtual host and add a proxy to get it working.

The reason for not working is that when you apply HTTPS, it will run on port 443. But now when you are applying an additional port in the URL with HTTPS then it will not run and it will show an error.

Reference for Apache reverse proxy: [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to empty the `@WebSocketGateway()` params, and add
`app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(app));` on the main file like this:

```js
    import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
    import { AppModule } from './app.module';
    import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
    import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
    
    async function bootstrap() {
      const fs = require('fs');
      const keyFile  = fs.readFileSync(`./certificates/private.key`);
      const certFile = fs.readFileSync(`./certificates/certificate.crt`);
      const ca = fs.readFileSync(`./certificates/ca_bundle.crt`);
    
      const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
        httpsOptions: {
          key: keyFile,
          cert: certFile,
          ca: ca,
        },
        cors: {
          origin: '*'
        }
      });
      app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
      app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(app));
      await app.listen(process.env.PORT!);
      console.log(`Listenning on port: ${process.env.PORT}`);
    }
    bootstrap();
```